# How to write interceptor in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, interceptor, react-redux

I have to pass token, received from server, after login to every api. so my question is how to write an interceptor which will append token on every api call. I am using 'request-promise' to call api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a wrapper (interface) function for your 'request-promise' calls:

```
export default class RequestInterface {
    constructor(accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    request({
        method,
        uri,
        body,
    }) {
        return rp({
            method,
            uri,
            body,
            qs: {
                access_token: this.accessToken,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

This way on every `RequestInterface.request()` call, you'll have your credentials there.

(I didn't test this but that's the basic idea)

Comment: so we are passing token in query string? is that secure?

Comment: I just added the token inside the qs object as an example, but if your api requires the token on the body, you can just add the token to the body object before the request `body.access_token = this.accessToken` and yes any of this methods are secure.