# Store api key in react webapp

Tags: api, reactjs, axios

My react web application uses axios to make an API post request. 
The API needs a parameter called token for each post request.

Is there a way to always add the token parameter for each post request I do, so I don't have to add it manually every time, and where to save this token in a secure location?

I feel what I do now is a bit redundant. Example:

```
axios.post('apiUrl.com', {
  token: 'abcdefg12345678',
  userId: 1
}).then(() => {//do something});
```

Comment: I just answered something similar in a different thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40206622/6219178

Comment: Ah great, I'll have a look at it! thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [axios interceptors](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors). If you add a request interceptor, you can make a change (add token) to each request:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
    config.data = config.data || {};
    config.data.token = 'abcdefg12345678';
    return config;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Should I put this code in my index.js or would another location be better for this?

Comment: Add it to the code that handles the token response.